# Is reading normal practical books about Judaism considered "Torah Studying"?

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, torah-study

Aside from the Tanakh, Talmud, Shulchan Aruch, Mishne Torah and the likes..... Is reading normal books about practical laws in Judaism considered "Torah Study"? I mean books like "To Be a Jew" for example. It deals with several aspect of every day Jewish life from Blessings, to Kashering, to going to Synagogue, explaining how to slaughter the animal, how to behave, modesty, etc.

Comment: how about just asking what constitutes torah study

Comment: How are you differentiating MT, SA, et al from practical halakha books?

Comment: @ShamanSTK since MT and SA are considered classical books if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @mil personally, I don't see that has a substantive difference. They weren't always classical and they were studied as Torah in their day.

Answer (score 1):

*Mishna B'rura* 554:5 says one may not issue halachic rulings or hear a court case on 9 *Av* (when Torah study is forbidden) "because law is Torah". The same would seem to me to apply to practical-*halacha* books of te sort you mention, but, as always, consult your rabbi if this is a practical question for you.

Comment: I'm missing the connection of this ruling and the more general ruling as it would answer the question.